# when click on button how to navigate to another page in dojox

Tags: dojo, navigation, ibm-mobilefirst

How to navigate to another page when click on `dojox.mobile.Button` using dojox in worklight.

I want to use only `dojox.mobile.Button` for this. Any one please help me how to do it.

How to go from page one to page two?

```js
function dojoInit() {
require([ "dojox/form/DropDownSelect", "dijit/form/Select", "dojo/ready",
 "dojo/parser", "dojox/mobile", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry",
 "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView", "dojox/mobile/View",
 "dojox/mobile/Overlay", "dojox/mobile/Heading",
 "dojox/mobile/TextArea", "dojox/mobile/SimpleDialog",
 "dojox/mobile/TextBox", "dojox/mobile/Button",
 "dojox/mobile/RadioButton", "dojox/mobile/Accordion", "dojox/mobile/GridLayout","dojo/parser",
 "dojox/mobile/ContentPane", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!" ], 
 
 function(ready) {
  ready(function() {}
 );
});
}
```

```html
<div id="M_LanguageView" class="selectLang"
    data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" data-dojo-props="selected:false">
    
    <img src="images/LanguageLogo.png" class="logo">
    <p>Select Your Language</p>
  
    <div align="center">
     <hr>
     <div>
      <form name="dojo" action="Login_en_View">
      <button id="M_LanguageView_en_Btn" class="selectLangbtn"
       data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" >
       <span class="btnlbl englishFont">ENGLISH</span> 
       <span class="lang_Indicationarrow"> </span>
      </button>
      </form>
     </div>
  
     <div>
      <button id="M_LanguageView_ar_Btn" class="selectLangbtn"
       data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button">
       <span class="btnlbl arabicFont">العربية</span> 
       <span class="lang_Indicationarrow"> </span>
      </button>
     </div>
    </div>
  
   </div> 
   
   <div id="Login_en_View" class="qHeaderBg englishFont" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
    
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="Login_en_View_Id"
     data-dojo-props="selected:false">
          
     <h1 id="Login_en_View_Header" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
       data-dojo-props="fixed:'top'" style="background: rgba(255, 198, 0, 1.0);">
      <img src="images/Header_en.png" class="headerImgAlignment">
     </h1>
     
     <div id="Login_en_View_DivId">
    
      <div class="errorMsg englishFont" id="Login_en_View_Error"></div>
    
      <div class="successMsg englishFont" id="Login_en_View_Success"></div>
    
      <label id="Login_en_View_Mno_lbl">Mobile Number :</label> 
       <input id="Login_en_View_Mno_txt" class="clearFields englishFont"
        data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==13 && event.keyCode != 8)return false;" type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" title="Non-negative integral number"> 
      
      <label id="Login_en_View_Uc_lbl">Password Code :</label> 
       <input id="Login_en_View_Uc_txt" class="clearFields englishFont" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox"
        onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==8 && event.keyCode != 8)return false;" type="password" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" title="Non-negative integral number">  
       
      <button id="Login_en_View_Sub_Btn" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" class="buttonProfile button englishFont">SUBMIT</button>
    
      <button id="Login_en_View_Reg_Btn" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" class="buttonProfile button englishFont">REGISTER</button>
    
            <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" id="Login_en_View_Ruc_Btn"  class="buttonProfile button englishFont marginBottom">RESED PASSWORD CODE</button>
     
     </div>
     
     <h2 id="Login_en_View_Footer" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
      data-dojo-props="fixed:'bottom'">
      <img src="images/Back.png" class="footerImgAlignment"
        onclick="goBack()" id="backLang">
     </h2>
     
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create form and in mention action attribute value as your destination page.

```
<form name="dojo" action="your_next_page">

<button></button>

</form>
```

Comment: 404 (Not Found) is comming

Comment: what is the name of your page that you want to show when you click on the button?

Comment: add like  action="Login_en_View.html"

Answer (score 0):

Use as below on click of the button from the first page.

```
var presentView = registry.byId("M_LanguageView");

presentView.performTransition("Login_en_View", direction ? direction : 1, "slide");
```